# useEffect fires and print statements run but no actual axios.post call runs reactjs

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django

I have a useEffect function that is firing due to `yearsBackSettings` changing and the console.log statements inside useEffect fire too:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("something changed")
    console.log(yearsBackSettings)
    if (userId) {
      const user_profile_api_url = BASE_URL + '/users/' + userId
      const request_data = {
        searches: recentSearches,
        display_settings: displaySettings,
        years_back_settings: yearsBackSettings
      }

      console.log("running user POST")
      console.log(request_data)

      axios.post(user_profile_api_url, request_data)
        .then(response => {
          console.log("user POST response")
          console.log(response)
        })
    }


  }, [recentSearches, displaySettings, yearsBackSettings])
```

As the image shows, changing yearsBackSettings causes this to run, which SHOULD make a post request with all the new settings:

[image]

However, for some reason there is nothing happening on the server except the stock search running:

```
the last updated time for stock ibm before save: 08/25/2022 08:13:30
stock was updated within the last 5 minutes...no need to make an api call
the last updated time for stock ibm after save: 08/25/2022 08:13:30
[25/Aug/2022 08:17:25] "POST /users/114260670592402026255 HTTP/1.1" 200 9
[25/Aug/2022 08:17:25] "GET /dividends/ibm/3/5 HTTP/1.1" 200 4055
the last updated time for stock ibm before save: 08/25/2022 08:13:30
stock was updated within the last 5 minutes...no need to make an api call
the last updated time for stock ibm after save: 08/25/2022 08:13:30
[25/Aug/2022 08:17:26] "GET /dividends/ibm/27/5 HTTP/1.1" 200 8271
the last updated time for stock ibm before save: 08/25/2022 08:13:30
stock was updated within the last 5 minutes...no need to make an api call
the last updated time for stock ibm after save: 08/25/2022 08:13:30
[25/Aug/2022 08:18:11] "GET /dividends/ibm/27/70 HTTP/1.1" 200 14734
```

The post to users there was an initial one when users loaded. If I sign in and sign out I lose the 70 years in the second component:

[image]

When I log out and log in it shows 27 years and 5 years, I lose the 70 because the /users POST didn't run

I have the following React main component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import axios from 'axios';


const SearchPage = ({userId}) => {

  const [recentSearches, setRecentSearches] = useState([DEFAULT_STOCK]);
  const [dividendsYearsBack, setDividendsYearsBack] = useState('3');
  const [debouncedDividendYearsBack, setDebouncedDividendYearsBack] = useState('3');
  const [earningsYearsBack, setEarningsYearsBack] = useState('5');
  const [debouncedEarningsYearsBack, setDebouncedEarningsYearsBack] = useState('5');
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  )
  const [displaySettings, setDisplaySettings] = useState([
      {setting_name: 'showYieldChange', visible: true},
      {setting_name: 'showAllDividends', visible: true},
      {setting_name: 'showAllEarnings', visible: true},
  ])
  const [yearsBackSettings, setYearsBackSettings] = useState([
      {section: 'dividendsYearsBack', years_back: 3},
      {section: 'earningsYearsBack', years_back: 5}
  ])

  const onTermUpdate = (term) => {
    const trimmed = term.trim()
    setTerm(trimmed);
  }

  debounceTerm(setDebouncedTerm, term, 1500);
  debounceTerm(setDebouncedDividendYearsBack, dividendsYearsBack, 1500);
  debounceTerm(setDebouncedEarningsYearsBack, earningsYearsBack, 1500);

  useEffect(() => {runSearch()}, [debouncedTerm]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // alert(dividendsYearsBack)
    if (dividendsYearsBack !== '' && earningsYearsBack !== '') {
      runSearch();
    }
  }, [debouncedDividendYearsBack, debouncedEarningsYearsBack])

  useEffect(() => {
    const yearsSettingsCopy = Object.assign(yearsBackSettings);
    const dividendsYearsBackSetting = yearsSettingsCopy.find((dict) => dict.section == 'dividendsYearsBack');
    dividendsYearsBackSetting.years_back = dividendsYearsBack;
    const earningsYearsBackSetting = yearsSettingsCopy.find((dict) => dict.section == 'earningsYearsBack');
    earningsYearsBackSetting.years_back = earningsYearsBack;
    setYearsBackSettings(yearsSettingsCopy);

  }, [dividendsYearsBack, earningsYearsBack])

  useEffect(() => {
    const dividendsYearsBackSetting = yearsBackSettings.find((dict) => dict.section == 'dividendsYearsBack');
    setDividendsYearsBack(dividendsYearsBackSetting.years_back);
    const earningsYearsBackSetting = yearsBackSettings.find((dict) => dict.section == 'earningsYearsBack');
    setEarningsYearsBack(earningsYearsBackSetting.years_back);
  }, [yearsBackSettings])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("user id changed")
    if (userId) {
      const user_profile_api_url = BASE_URL + '/users/' + userId
      axios.get(user_profile_api_url, {})
        .then(response => {
          // console.log(response)

          const recent_searches_response = response.data.searches;
          const new_recent_searches = [];
          recent_searches_response.map(dict => {
            new_recent_searches.push(dict.search_term)
          })
          setRecentSearches(new_recent_searches);
          setDisplaySettings(response.data.display_settings);
          setYearsBackSettings(response.data.years_back_settings);

        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("error in getting user profile: ", error.message)
        })
    }
  }, [userId])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("something changed")
    console.log(yearsBackSettings)
    if (userId) {
      const user_profile_api_url = BASE_URL + '/users/' + userId
      const request_data = {
        searches: recentSearches,
        display_settings: displaySettings,
        years_back_settings: yearsBackSettings
      }

      console.log("running user POST")
      console.log(request_data)

      axios.post(user_profile_api_url, request_data)
        .then(response => {
          console.log("user POST response")
          console.log(response)
        })
    }


  }, [recentSearches, displaySettings, yearsBackSettings])



  return (

      <div className="ui segment">
        {renderMainContent()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { userId: state.auth.userId };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps
)(SearchPage);

// export default SearchPage;
```

The yearsBackSettings is showing up changed to 27 and 70 (from the picture) but the POST request doesn't fire. How can I get these settings to save when the settings change?

The issue is that the post doesnt run when I update the years back settings:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("running user profile post");
    const user_profile_api_url = BASE_URL + '/users/' + userId
    const request_data = {
      searches: recentSearches,
      display_settings: displaySettings,
      years_back_settings: yearsBackSettings
    }

    axios.post(user_profile_api_url, request_data)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })

  }, [recentSearches, displaySettings, yearsBackSettings])
```

this doesnt run when yearsBackSettings changes. I am logging yearsBackSettings to console and it is certainly changed, but the post request to user profile doesnt fire

I think the issue is here:

```
  useEffect((

) => {
    const dividendsYearsBackSetting = yearsBackSettings.find((dict) => dict.section == 'dividendsYearsBack');
    dividendsYearsBackSetting.years_back = dividendsYearsBack;
    const earningsYearsBackSetting = yearsBackSettings.find((dict) => dict.section == 'earningsYearsBack');
    earningsYearsBackSetting.years_back = earningsYearsBack;
    setYearsBackSettings(yearsBackSettings);

  }, [dividendsYearsBack, earningsYearsBack])
```

as an example, I tried doing any useEffect with yearsBackSettings, and it never works. I have changed the settings a few times and the alert does not fire:

```
useEffect(() => {
    alert("years back settings changed")
  }, [yearsBackSettings])
```

Comment: Lookup the network console, as you console.log a response object with status `200` the request actually DOES fire. Where in your python code do you log "it works"?

Comment: the bigger issue is that even tho the request appears to run (it returns the response coded in the view) the new settings don't actually save for some reason

Answer (score 5):

The issue is somewhere in your python server code, in your console you can see that you are actually logging a response object with a 200 response code, meaning your server doesn't crash during the actual request.

There might be a problem in your server side logging causing the request to not show up, I would look at that first.

Comment: let me work on this tonight I had so many other bugs to fix

Comment: sorry I found another issue